# Trying to import a Python module from another repo (within VSCode)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Currently have two repos cloned onto VSCode. When I open VSCode my directory structure looks like this:

```
- Repo1
  - Base 1
    - Scripts
      -Code.py
- Repo2
  - testcode.py
```

This one python file that I am trying to execute has the following import statements:

```
from repo2.testcode import testmodule
```

However, python is not recognizing this as a module... and the following error message is being returned:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'Repo2'.
```

I did some research and realized that I need to do either: Do I need to make a package? Or do I need to add to the module path import statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use packages, you can specify the path to another local package in setup.py.

Your overall structure would be:

```
|-- Repo1/
|   |-- setup.py
|   |-- Repo1/
│   |    |-- __init__.py
|   |    |--Code.py
|   |-- tests/
|   |    |--test_Code.py
|
|-- Repo2/
|   |-- setup.py
|   |-- Repo2/
│   |    |-- __init__.py
|   |    |--testcode.py
```

Repo1/setup.py.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os

# dynamically determine the path to Repo2
local_name = "Repo2"
local_path = os.getcwd().split(os.sep)
local_path = os.sep.join(local_path[0:local_path.index(local_name)])
local_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_name)


setup(
    name="Repo1",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="First Repo",
    python_requires=">=3.5.0",
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'SomePyPIPackage',
        f"{local_name} @ file://localhost/{local_path}#egg={local_name}"
    ]
)
```

The setup.py file in Repo2 would be similar, but wouldn't have the install_requires localhost portion.

Then when you are in the top level directory for Repo1 you can run (don't forget the dot at the end):

```
# would have to reinstall if you make changes to Repo2
pip install .

# or install in editable mode
pip install -e .
```

Then in Repo1 you should be able to use:

```
from repo2.testcode import testmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code before the import statement

```
import os,sys,inspect
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)
```

It will take you to the parent directory and will import the module from there

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named
```

This means the python interpreter could not find this package under the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or the package was damaged.

You can get the `PYTHONPATH` through this code:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint

pprint(sys.path)
```

You can check whether you can find the parent folder of the Repo2 folder.

**Solution:**

VSCode provides a method to modify the PYTHONPATH, but only works in debugging mode:

```
"env": {"PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"}, //${workspaceFolder} means the path of the folder opened in VS Code. Modify it to the path of the parent folder of Repo2.
```

Or modify the path manually in the python file:

```
sys.path.append("parent folder path of the Repo2 folder")
```

It should be placed ahead of the import statement.